# Laravel: each() and map() methods ignore the previous filtering with filter(), when() and where()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Need some help here, I’ve been breaking my head last evening and this morning, and cannot get through.
Essentially I’m trying to get this table:

```
           Gross value
Person1
Person2
Person3
All
```

I want to filter `$users` according to `$person`: if `$person` is an integer (i.e., the id of a user), just get its appointments, else if `$person` is the string 'all', get everyone’s appointments.

The problem is, no matter how I try to filter (be it with a `when()` method, or with a `filter()` method), it never works, because when I use the `each()` or `map()` methods, `$filtered_users` is always the whole collection of `App\Eloquent\User`, unfiltered!!
Here's the code:

```
$rows[] = $users
// 1) Using filter
    ->filter(function ($users) use($person) {
        return $person === 'all' || $users->id == $person;})


// 2) Using when
    ->when($person !== 'all', function ($users) use($person) {
        return $users->where('id', $person);})

    ->map(function ($filtered_users) { // Using map here, but each produces the same problem
        return $filtered_users->each(function ($user) {
            return $user->appointments()->first()->invoices()->first()->gross;    // This still needs work, but not the point of the exercise
        });});
```

I’m at a loss, read the eloquent documentation, went through SOF, nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: post a sample json return  by your collection, then post your desired output

Answer (score 0):

first consider when you are using filter, your query fetch all data from Database and then in "filter()" some data remove from collection.

its better to see your code in more details,

now it seems you need to use filter like this:

```
    $collection = Gross::get();
    $filtered = $collection->filter(function ($users) use($person) {
        return $person === 'all' || $users->id == $person;
    });
    $newCollection = $filtered->all();
```

$newCollection contains your filtered data